# Use local variable to avoid race condition

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following `Runnable` implementation:

```
public class Example implements Runnable
{
    private Thread runThread = null;

    // Runs in its own thread
    @Override
    public void run() {
        assert runThread == null;  // must not call run() twice
        runThread = Thread.currentThread();
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // do something
            }
        } finally {
            runThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Might be called from another thread
    public void stop() {
        Thread t = runThread;   // use temporary variable to avoid race condition with run()
        if (t != null) {
            // without the temporary variable, the run() thread could be set to null at this point
            t.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions about this code:

1. Is it valid to use a temporary local variable to store an object that might be set to null by another thread or do I need additional synchronization here?
2. Is this a good way to provide a stopping mechanism for runnable, or should I just let the owner of the `Example` instance handle that?

Comment: I would just use a boolean `isRunning`. The `run` method loops while this boolean is `true` and `stop` just sets it to `false`.

Comment: If you use such a field, you should make it `volatile`.

Comment: The Runnable should notmake assumptions on how it's run and how many times it's executed, IMO. The code creating the thread should be the one stopping it. The stop() method shouldn't be in the Runnable.